# How to map CJK input to english alphabet for purposes of key bindings and evil?

Tags: keyboard-layout

When I type in a CJK language, I would still like to be able to use emacs key bindings such as <kbd>M-x</kbd>, as well as vi keys in evil-mode normal-state. Is there a way to make emacs register the keyboard input as a US keyboard only when a modifier is pressed? Also, maybe more difficult, is there a way to make evil normal state register keypresses in the US keyboard (without manually mapping every single command to its CJK equivalent)?

Comment: One way to achieve this is to use a US keyboard layout all the time, and use Emacs' input methods to type CJK text (e.g. `C-u C-\ chinese-py` etc). It would be nice to have Emacs handle this automatically when a non-Latin keyboard layout is selected in the OS, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [select an input method](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html).  It will allow you to use, say, a QWERTY keyboard layout for commands, but switch between QWERTY and CJK for inserting text.

The keybinding for `toggle-input-method` is set to `C-\` by default.  You can also customize the `default-input-method` variable.